# Check whether file is in Windows installation drive and whether drive is connected

Tags: c++, windows

Is there a way to check if the my process can check whether its directory is on the Windows installation drive? For example, my file is on the D: drive but Windows is on the C: drive.

I want this because the file should be launched from an external drive.

With this can you also check whether the drive currently exists? Again an example, the file is on a USB in D:, can you check if the D drive still exists while the program is running? Like whether the USB in unplugged while running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split up the problem into the individual components:

- Find the executable's path: [C++ Windows - How to get process path from its PID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933113/c-windows-how-to-get-process-path-from-its-pid)
- Get Windows' own installation path: [Find windows folder programatically in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499354/find-windows-folder-programatically-in-c-sharp), if you can port this to C++
- Check that the former is not in the latter
- Use a function like `access()` to check whether the executable's path is still accessible.